# Remove query parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a complex multi-select filter page so I'm grouping filters like this `http://localhost:3000/search?id[]=101404&id[]=7267261`. I'm using `URLSearchParams()` to manage my URLs.

The only thing that is not working is *removing* a parameter once it has been unchecked. I tried using the `URLSearchParams.delete()`, but it only accepts a single parameter, name. If I pass id[], it removes ALL id[]'s, not just the one I want to be deleted.

EDIT: based on recommendations, I have this new code (see old code below). Hoping someone has a far more elegant solution.

```
 setQueryParams = (param = null, value = null, category = null) => {
    ....

      // parameter exists but value is false
    } else if (param && !value) {
        // find all values for category and filter out unchecked value
        const values = params.getAll(`${category}[]`).filter(category => category !== param)
        // remove entire category from URLSearchParams
        params.delete(`${category}[]`)
        // loop over filtered list and append them BACK to URLSearchParams
        values.forEach((value) => {
          params.append(`${category}[]`, value)
        });
    }

    this.setState({
      query: params.toString()
    });
  }
```

The only other way I can think of is to write some Regexp, which I wasn't able to get it to work anyway. My params are encoded, so shouldn't something like this work? I can't even get this to work in console... 
`"id%5B%5D=101404&id%5B%5D=7267261".replace(/\%5\%D/,'')`
`"id%5B%5D=101404&id%5B%5D=7267261".replace(/%5%D/,'')`
`"id%5B%5D=101404&id%5B%5D=7267261".replace(/\[\]/,'')`

None of these work. Here is my code generating the query parameters.

```
  setQueryParams = (param = null, value = null, category = null) => {
    const query = this.state.query;
    // get current location
    const location = this.props.location.search;

    // Set params based on whether component mount or filter change
    const params = param ? new URLSearchParams(query) : new URLSearchParams(location);

    // value must be equal to true
    if (param && value) {
      params.append(`${category}[]`, param);

      // parameter exists but value is false
    } else if (param && !value) {
      params.delete(category);
    }

    this.setState({
      query: params.toString()
    });
  }
```

Comment: DO they both need to be called id[]? or could you rename one to id[1]?

Comment: id[1]= actually crashes the server, so that won't work =/

Comment: how about id1 without the square brackets or are they required?

Comment: By using the format `http://localhost:3000/search?id[]=101404&id[]=7267261` or alternatively, `id=[id, id]` the server processes them as an array `  Parameters: {"id"=>["101404", "7267261"]}` which then allows me to loop through them instead of having to create a database query for every single individual parameter

Answer (score 2):

What if you use the [`getAll('id[]')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/getAll), iterate over the results and [`append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/append) the ones you want.

Although it's not that elegant of a solution, I think it's still better than the regex approach.

Comment: This is a horribly non-elegant solution....but it works so I can't really complain. I had to loop over all of the values, filter the value that was unselected out, then iterate over the filtered list and append each one back to the query.

Comment: Well, a man's gotta do, what a man's gotta do to make things work :) I'm glad it works for you. Trust me, this solution is clearer and much easier to maintain than the regex one. And I'm telling you this as an experienced Perl developer who works with regexes quite often.

Answer (score 0):

```
 setQueryParams = (param = null, value = null, category = null) => {
    ....

      // parameter exists but value is false
    } else if (param && !value) {
        // find all values for category and filter out unchecked value
        const values = params.getAll(`${category}[]`).filter(category => category !== param)
        // remove entire category from URLSearchParams
        params.delete(`${category}[]`)
        // loop over filtered list and append them BACK to URLSearchParams
        values.forEach((value) => {
          params.append(`${category}[]`, value)
        });
    }

    this.setState({
      query: params.toString()
    });
  }
```